# Undefined methods length and next! for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def encrypt(x)
  index = 0
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  while index < x.length
    letter = x[index]
    if letter == ' '
      print ' '
      index += 1
    elsif letter == "z"
      print "a"
      index += 1
    else
      letter = alphabet[letter].next!
      index += 1
      print letter
    end
  end
end

def decrypt(x)
  number = 0
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  while number < x.length
    green = x[number]
    if green == ' '
      print ' '
      number += 1
    else
      red = alphabet.index(green)
      red = red.to_i
      blue = red - 1
      yellow = alphabet[blue]
      print yellow
      number += 1
    end
  end
end
```

If I add a capital letter such as in:

```
encrypt("Dhd  d hd h")
```

it returns:

```
undefined method `next!' for nil:NilClass
(repl):13:in `encrypt'
(repl):39:in `initialize'
```

or if I try to use both methods:

```
encrypt(decrypt("Dhddhdh"))
```

it returns

```
undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
(repl):4:in `encrypt'
(repl):39:in `initialize'
```

I thought it was due to having a space in the argument, and added an `if`/ `else` for that, but no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you expecting to remove the case when encrypting or preserve it (typically in these exercises the case is removed, because the goal is not to cover all possible characters, just to get you thinking about handling strings)? Also, please consider using descriptive names for your variables in the decrypt routine, not arbitrary names such as colours - using names like you do the encrypt routine is good practice in general, and important for other people reading your code as it speeds up understanding of what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both cases your alphabeth should include *lowercase* and *downcase* caracteres:

> alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Other problem with your code is, instead printing the caracteres, I suggest you to return a value:

```
def encrypt(x)
  index = 0
  encrypted = ""
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  while index < x.length
    letter = x[index]
    if letter == ' '
      encrypted << ' '
    elsif letter == "z"
       encrypted << "a"
    elsif letter == "Z"
      encrypted << "A"
    else
       letter = alphabet[letter].next!
       encrypted << letter
    end

    index += 1
  end

  encrypted
end
```

Decrypt method:

```
def decrypt(x)
 index = 0
  decrypted = ""
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  while index < x.length
    letter = x[index]
    if letter == ' '
      decrypted << ' '
    elsif letter == "A"
      decrypted << "Z"
    else
      blue = alphabet.index(letter) - 1
      decrypted << alphabet[blue]
    end

    index += 1
  end

  decrypted
end
```

Comment: Now you have put the full routine, you need to fix the `elsif letter == "z"` routine for the new alphabet (if input is "Z", output will be "AA", which won't decrypt back to "Z")

Comment: @NeilSlater got it... let me see how to handle this

Comment: @NeilSlater what about now?

Comment: Yes looks like it works to me, and OP seems to agree.